# How can I use Logo of company to fetch specific data from database

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

Basically i have three table of cars . In which one table contain make Name other is about model and third contain the description of these cars all of these table are connect with each other by foreign key constraints . But now I want to use logo of the company to fetch specific data from tables these logos Are not stored in database.

[As you can see i use inner join to fetch data,  when ever I click on the logo Logo will Get id of the model and terminate to next page name as check.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqIav.png)  `

[As you see these are the logos of auto company but when I click on any logo it will terminate to next page but does not carry any id ?[][2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owijt.png)

Comment: Please don't include your code as an image, paste it in your question. This way nobody can't copy your code and test it locally if they need to.

Comment: I think the problem is how you are getting `id` in `check.php` please show code which you are using to fetch `id` in check.php

Comment: can i send you code personly

Comment: Sir with noname no problem is not there in check.php caus code doesn't carry any model id to that check.php page

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to reach id outside of while statement. All logic should be inside while statement 
`while() {
//logic
}`

Comment: exactly Sir . but when i placed all the logic inside the while statment then the logos are duplicate as the number of id exist in the table